# 文字列をbyteスライスした結果の数字は何を示しているのでしょうか？

Tags: go

golangにて、以下のようにstringの"abcdef"をbyteスライスにすると、数字になります。
逆に、byteスライスをstringでキャストすると文字列が返ってきます。

一体この数字は何を示しているのでしょうか。

```
abcdef => 97 98 99 100 101 102 103
```

連番になっているので、何かに準拠しているのだとは思うのですが…

```
[]byte("abcdefg") => 97 98 99 100 101 102 103

string([]byte{97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103}) => abcdef
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

これは UTF-8 という文字コードで文字列をエンコードした結果の数値です。特に abcdefg という文字列では、[ASCII](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)という古くから使われている文字コードと一致します。

コンピュータの内部では全て数値でデータを保存しているので、文字列データも内部的には数値の列として保存されています。Go においては文字列は全て Unicode の UTF-8 という文字コードのルールに従って数値化されており、このルールに従うと `"a"` は 97、`"b"` は 98、といった風になります。UTF-8 や ASCII では a～z、A～Z の文字に対応する数値はそれぞれ連番になっており、`"abc"` を数値列にすると連番になったというわけです。

少しだけ注意が必要なのは、1 文字 1 byte という訳ではないということです。たとえば……：

```
func printBytes(s string) {
    fmt.Println([]byte(s))
}

func main() {
    printBytes("a")
    printBytes("あ")
    printBytes("α")
    printBytes("")
    printBytes("‍‍‍")
}
```

出力：

```
[97]
[227 129 130]
[206 177]
[240 159 152 139]
[240 159 145 168 226 128 141 240 159 145 169 226 128 141 240 159 145 166 226 128 141 240 159 145 166]
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KCoJqjlubGq)

Comment: とても詳しく教えていただきありがとうございます！！
golangを書いていく上では、コンピュータ内部でデータがどう扱われているかを意識することは大切ですね。

‍‍‍が25byteあるのは驚きでした。mysqlなどで文字コードをマルチバイトに対応しないと絵文字が使えないと言うところと繋がり理解が進みました。

ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2):

アスキーコードの10進数でないかと思います。
以下を参照してください
http://www3.nit.ac.jp/~tamura/ex2/ascii.html

Comment: 他の方の回答にもあったのですが、その通りでした。回答ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 1):

「a」「b」「c」…それぞれの文字に割り当てられているASCIIコードです。

http://e-words.jp/p/r-ascii.html

Comment: ASCIIコード(文字コード)の話だったのですね、ありがとうございます。